# Call matlab from netbeans using matlabcontrol

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

help me please on this! When I try to call my matlab function using matlabcontrol from java, it tells me the system could not find the file specified.

```
package matcontro;

import matlabcontrol.*;

public class HelloWorld

 {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
     {
         // create proxy
         MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                 .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                 .build();
         MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy(); 

         // call builtin function
         proxy.eval("disp('hello world')");

         // call user-defined function (must be on the path)
         proxy.eval("addpath('C:\\ Users\\HASENDE\\My Documents\\MATLAB')");
         proxy.feval("myfunc");
         proxy.eval("rmpath('C:\\ Users\\HASENDE\\My Documents\\MATLAB')");

         // close connection
         proxy.disconnect();
     }
 }
```

The error that I get is below;

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException: Could not launch MATLAB. Command: [matlab, -r, javaaddpath 'C:\Users\HASENDE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java Classpath Libraries\matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabClassLoaderHelper.configureClassLoading(); javarmpath 'C:\Users\HASENDE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java Classpath Libraries\matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabConnector.connectFromMatlab('PROXY_RECEIVER_01caa56d-9ed7-4e39-a45b-345051024d49', 2100);]

at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.createProcess(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:305) at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.requestProxy(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:116)

at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:134)

    at matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(MatlabProxyFactory.java:81)

    at matcontro.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:21)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "matlab": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.createProcess(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:292) ... 4 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:188)

    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)

    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)   ... 5 more

Java Result: 1
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)